# How can i run simple loop with conditional variables in ansible playbook from ansible AWX with multi select survey?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

The goal is to create user in multiple databases, each database has it's own port, ip and priv set. In host I'm only passing name and based on the name it's define all variables.

This is variables JSON from AWX:

{
"username": "ansible",
"password": "123456",
"host": [
"yan_local",
"QA1_Backgammon"
],
"permissions": "SELECT,SHOW VIEW"
}

Without loop section with only one host it's working fine

I'm trying to do a loop but it's not working

Here is my code:

````
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  vars:
     port: "{{ '3306' if host == 'yan_local' else '3310' if host == 'DEV_Backgammon' else '3320' if host == 'DEV_Spades' else '3330' if host == 'DEV_Rummy' else '3311' if host == 'QA1_Backgammon' else '3321' if host == 'QA1_Spades' else '3331' if host == 'QA1_Rummy' else '3341' if host == 'QA1_Domino' else '3351' if host == 'QA1_CasualRummy' else '3313' if host == 'QA2_Backgammon' else '3323' if host == 'QA2_Spades' else '3312' if host == 'Stage_Backgammon' else '3322' if host == 'Stage_Spades' else '3332' if host == 'Stage_Rummy' }}"
     database_name: "{{ '10.42.0.38' if host == 'yan_local' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'DEV_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'DEV_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'DEV_Rummy' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Rummy' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Domino' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_CasualRummy' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA2_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA2_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'Stage_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'Stage_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'Stage_Rummy' }}"
     database: "{{ 'yan' if host == 'yan_local' else 'backgammon' if host == 'DEV_Backgammon' else 'spades' if host == 'DEV_Spades' else 'rummy' if host == 'DEV_Rummy' else 'backgammon' if host == 'QA1_Backgammon' else '3321' if host == 'spades' else 'rummy' if host == 'QA1_Rummy' else 'backgammon' if host == 'QA1_Domino' else 'rummy' if host == 'QA1_CasualRummy' else 'backgammon' if host == 'QA2_Backgammon' else '3323' if host == 'spades' else 'backgammon' if host == 'Stage_Backgammon' else 'spades' if host == 'Stage_Spades' else '3332' if host == 'rummy' }}"
     dbpassword_yan: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'qa/ansible', region='us-west-2') | from_json | json_query('password') }}"
     dbpassword_qa: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'qa/ansible', region='us-west-2') | from_json | json_query('db_pass') }}"
     dbpassword: "{{ lookup('vars', 'dbpassword_yan') if host == 'yan_local' else lookup('vars', 'dbpassword_qa') if host != 'yan_local' }}"
     host: []

  tasks:
  - name:  
    pip:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       state: present
    with_items:
          - PyMySQL
          - boto
          - boto3
          - botocore
          - jmespath   
          
    
  - name: Database details
    debug: 
       msg: '{{ database_name }}/{{ database }}-{{ host }}:{{ port }}'
     
  - name: Create database user with name "{{ username }}" and password "{{ password }}" 
    community.mysql.mysql_user:
        login_host: "{{ item }}"
        login_port: "{{ '3306' if host == 'yan_local' else '3310' if host == 'DEV_Backgammon' else '3320' if host == 'DEV_Spades' else '3330' if host == 'DEV_Rummy' else '3311' if host == 'QA1_Backgammon' else '3321' if host == 'QA1_Spades' else '3331' if host == 'QA1_Rummy' else '3341' if host == 'QA1_Domino' else '3351' if host == 'QA1_CasualRummy' else '3313' if host == 'QA2_Backgammon' else '3323' if host == 'QA2_Spades' else '3312' if host == 'Stage_Backgammon' else '3322' if host == 'Stage_Spades' else '3332' if host == 'Stage_Rummy' }}"
        login_user: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'qa/ansible', region='us-west-2') | from_json | json_query('user') }}"
        login_password: "{{ dbpassword }}"
        host: '%'
        password: "{{ password }}"
        name: "{{ username }}"
        priv: "{{ 'yan' if host == 'yan_local' else 'backgammon' if host == 'DEV_Backgammon' else 'spades' if host == 'DEV_Spades' else 'rummy' if host == 'DEV_Rummy' else 'backgammon' if host == 'QA1_Backgammon' else '3321' if host == 'spades' else 'rummy' if host == 'QA1_Rummy' else 'backgammon' if host == 'QA1_Domino' else 'rummy' if host == 'QA1_CasualRummy' else 'backgammon' if host == 'QA2_Backgammon' else '3323' if host == 'spades' else 'backgammon' if host == 'Stage_Backgammon' else 'spades' if host == 'Stage_Spades' else '3332' if host == 'rummy' }}.*:{{ permissions }}"
        state: present
    when: username != "root23" and username != "root22"
    loop: "{{ database_name }}"

    
  - name: Database details
    debug: 
       msg: '{{ database_name }}/{{ database }}-{{ host }}:{{ port }}'```

I'm getting error:

```{
  "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ '10.42.0.38' if host == 'yan_local' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'DEV_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'DEV_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'DEV_Rummy' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Rummy' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_Domino' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA1_CasualRummy' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA2_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'QA2_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'Stage_Backgammon' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'Stage_Spades' else '172.31.0.176' if host == 'Stage_Rummy' }}: the inline if-expression on line 1 evaluated to false and no else section was defined.\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/sql-playbook.yml': line 25, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Database details\n    ^ here\n",
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

I can do set_facts for each item in [host] array and create another array using when condition, for example:

```
    set_fact: 
     dbs: "{{dbs|default([]) + [{'host': {'port': 3332, 'database': 'rummy', 'database_name': '172.31.0.176', 'dbpassword': dbpassword_qa }}] }}"
    when: item == 'Stage_Rummy'    
    loop:
      "{{host}}"

  - name: set_facts
    set_fact: 
     dbs: "{{dbs|default([]) + [{'host': {'port': 3322, 'database': 'spades', 'database_name': '172.31.0.176', 'dbpassword': dbpassword_qa }}] }}"
    when: item == 'Stage_Spades'    
    loop:
      "{{host}}"

  - name: set_facts
    set_fact: 
     dbs: "{{dbs|default([]) + [{'host': {'port': 3306, 'database': 'yan', 'database_name': '10.42.0.184', 'dbpassword': dbpassword_yan }}] }}"
    when: item == 'yan_local'    
    loop:
      "{{host}}"
```

Then i can loop over new array:

```
    community.mysql.mysql_user:
        login_host: "{{ item.host.database_name }}"
        login_port: "{{ item.host.port }}"
        login_user: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'qa/ansible', region='us-west-2') | from_json | json_query('user') }}"
        login_password: "{{ item.host.dbpassword }}"
        host: '%'
        password: "{{ password }}"
        name: "{{ username }}"
        priv: '{{ item.host.database }}.*:{{ permissions }}'
        state: present
    when: username != "root" and username != "root22"
    loop:
       "{{ dbs }}"
```

Assuming that I transfer only yan_local from AWX, it will only trigger third task and ignore 2 first, or it will contain all 3 hosts, then it will create array dbs with this 3 hosts.

{dbs|default([]) syntax will create new array if not exist with empty value  and add there provided values from set_facts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the definition of the variables according to:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    host: QA1_Backgammon
    json_awx:
      username: ansible
      password: 123456
      host:
        - yan_local
        - QA1_Backgammon
      permissions: "SELECT,SHOW VIEW"

    dbhosts:
      - name: yan_local
        login_port: 3306
        login_host: '10.42.0.38'
        login_user: 'login'
        login_password: 'password'
        database: yan
        host: '%'
      - name: QA1_Backgammon
        login_port: 3311
        login_host: '172.31.0.176'
        login_user: 'login'
        login_password: 'password'
        database: backgammon
        host: '%'

  tasks:
    - name: Set dbh variable
      vars:
        entry: "{{ dbhosts
                    | selectattr('name','equalto',item)
                    | flatten
                    | combine({ 'permissions':json_awx.permissions,
                                'username':json_awx.username,
                                'password':json_awx.password }) }}"
      set_fact:
        dbh: "{{ dbh
                  | default([])
                  + [ entry ] }}"
      loop: "{{ json_awx.host }}"

    - name: Create database user 
      debug:
        msg:
          login_host: "{{ item.login_host }}"
          login_port: "{{ item.login_port }}"
          login_user: "{{ item.login_user }}"
          login_password: "{{ item.login_password }}"
          host: "{{ item.host }}"
          password: "{{ item.password }}"
          name: "{{ item.username }}"
          priv: "{{ item.database }}.*:{{ item.permissions }}"
      loop: "{{ dbh }}"
      when:
        - item.username != 'root22'
        - item.username != 'root23'
        - item.name == host
```

and the output

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************

TASK [Set dbh variable] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=yan_local)
ok: [localhost] => (item=QA1_Backgammon)

TASK [Create database user] ***********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'yan_local', 'login_port': 3306, 'login_host': '10.42.0.38', 'login_user': 'login', 'login_password': 'password', 'database': 'yan', 'host': '%', 'permissions': 'SELECT,SHOW VIEW', 'username': 'ansible', 'password': 123456})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'QA1_Backgammon', 'login_port': 3311, 'login_host': '172.31.0.176', 'login_user': 'login', 'login_password': 'password', 'database': 'backgammon', 'host': '%', 'permissions': 'SELECT,SHOW VIEW', 'username': 'ansible', 'password': 123456}) => {
    "msg": {
        "host": "%",
        "login_host": "172.31.0.176",
        "login_password": "password",
        "login_port": "3311",
        "login_user": "login",
        "name": "ansible",
        "password": "123456",
        "priv": "backgammon.*:SELECT,SHOW VIEW"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
```

Comment: But I don’t see where in your code you set conditions, idea is according to the name of DB’s set port, host, database and then create dynamic list and loop over that list. In dbhosts all parameters should be conditional, so when I run playbook from AWX I only mention name of the database

Comment: In the task Create database user remove the condition item.name == host and put item.database == 'backgammon' or whatever

Comment: If you want to create dbhost dynamically, you must use jinja2. login_port: "{% if host=='QA1_Backgammon' %}23306{% elseif host=='yan' %}3360{% else %}1234{% endif %}"

Comment: I need another solution, I need to create dynamic array/ list based on host list I provide in AWX, if I provided host yan_local, qa_backgammon then it’s should create array/list with port/ database/ db_name etc based on the name using conditions if and else, then to do item.name, item.port etc and loop over it, how I can do it?